# “choregraphe-suite-2.8.6.23-mac64-setup” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I am trying to install Choregraphe Suite on my macOS Catalina (v10.15.7) from the softbankrobotics website but I get this message:

[image: the error that is preventing the installation]

Website link: https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/choregraphe-suite/choregraphe-suite-installation-guide#desktop-installation

I don't know what I'm missing in order to run the installation on my laptop. I would appreciate it if anyone can help me on this.

Update: I left clicked it and it opened in command line. I went into the choregraphe-folder/bin/naoqi-bin and when I executed the file I got this:

```
Last login: Sat Nov  7 09:05:34 on ttys000
/Users/name/EEP_work/choregraphe-suite-2.8.6.23-mac64/bin/naoqi-bin ; exit;
name@Mahlas-MBP ~ % /Users/name/EEP_work/choregraphe-suite-2.8.6.23-mac64/bin/naoqi-bin ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
Referenced from: /Users/name/EEP_work/choregraphe-suite-2.8.6.23-mac64/bin/naoqi-bin
Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      

[Process completed]
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the system settings > security & privacy and explicitly allow the opening of the installer (screenshot attached).

[allow opening of installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Blpt.png)

It will then bring up a second dialog:

"macOS cannot verify the developer of “choregraphe-suite-2.8.6.23-mac64-setup”. Are you sure you want to open it?

By opening this app, you will be overriding system security which can expose your computer and personal information to malware that may harm your Mac or compromise your privacy."

You can then click on "Open", but for my Mac (10.15.7) the installer crashes directly afterwards and I cannot install anything.

[allow installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMzJQ.png)

It seems impossible to install Choregraphe on a recent Mac OS X. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

'Allow install from internet' is the step you have to go over for all 3rd party apps(always happening) for macs. But still 'choregraphe' setup file didn't worked.

I hope my solution helps, i searched a lot too :)

install not setup file, try binaries one[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ0SU.png), and unzip. Open file you will see 'choregraphe' unix executable file, i clicked that file and app worked, best

P.s. i am not expert or anything that is only way i was able to make it work for my MacOs 10.15.7 (Catalina)

Comment: Thank you for trying it out! I followed your steps but I still could not run it. It kept saying the same message :(

Comment: @MahlaNasr , when i was looking solution, i ask NAO support about Catalina, I get message back from NAO support, they are saying Catalina not supported. However, I am still able to use from binaries. Too bad they don't actually support. There is another way, that one is complicated but has to work. You can install virtual box, and run linux (install in that linux) i didn't try but Linux should be sported well.

Comment: oh I see. I went to update my MacBook to Big Sur as well but did not help. Could you please tell me the steps you took to run the binarise file as it still doesn't work when I click on the 'choregraphe' unix executable file. There should be a wizard opening to let me install the IDE. I even changed the security settings but it was not much of a help. I have installed the virtual box as well but still researching on how to set it up. Thank you for your support, really appreciated!